# Issues loading a photo loop with OwlCarousel

Tags: javascript, php, html, owl-carousel

I have an existing and working php loop that displays thumbnails of all the photos from the query, but it's too many photos and I want to incorporate a slideshow for the images so I've started trying OwlCarousel.

I downloaded it into my folder

Currently my site folder structure is like this

```
root
|
templates.php

OwlCarousel
    |
    Dist
        |
        owl.carousel.min.js

        Assets
            |
            owl.carousel.min.css
            owl.theme.default.min.css
```

But I'm trying to use it on the site and where I once had my huge array of images from my php loop there are now none. I don't know if I've incorrectly included the files or if I'm actually using the JS for OwlCarousel wrong.

What should I do from here?

In my templates.php file:

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  nav:true,
  responsive:{
         0:{
             items:1
         },
         600:{
             items:3
         },
         1000:{
             items:5
         }
     }
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>

 <div role="tabpanel" id="images<?php echo $n_id?>" class="tab-pane fade show active">
      <div class="owl-carousel">
    <?php foreach ($imageResult as $im): ?>
      <?php if($im['type'] == 'content'){?>
       <img src="<?php echo $im['url']; ?>" style="max-width:200px; max-height:200px;">
      <?php } ?>
      <?php endforeach?>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: FYI the `owl-carousel` class has a property `display:none` so it is hidden. I don’t see where you’ve referenced the owl.carousel.min.js so without the plugin actually initialising it will always be hidden.

Comment: I link it in my js src section, it's the 3rd link in that section. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now.

Comment: Does the php actually output the images?

Comment: Basically, once I remove the div around the images with the owl-carousel class then they show

Comment: @Cue If I inspect the page, I can remove the display:none and it shows the source elements there, but it seems like something is missing for the actual functionality